# Symfony 4 - How to create queue if it not exists

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp, symfony4

I'm using [Symfony Messenger Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html) in my Symfony 4 application to communicate with RabbitMQ.

```
# config/packages/messenger.yaml

framework:
messenger:
    transports:
        new_orders: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%new_orders'
        orders_progress: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%orders_progress'

    routing:
        'App\ValueObject\Message\OrderMessage': new_orders
        'App\ValueObject\Message\OrderProgressMessage': orders_progress
```

Usage in command (just a snippet):

```
# src/Command/CollectOrdersCommand.php
class CollectOrdersCommand extends Command
{
    public function __construct(MessageBusInterface $queue);

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): void
    {
        $msg = new OrderMessage();
        $this->queue->dispatch($msg);
    }
}
```

I run the app in Docker containers. If I launch it from the scratch, RabbitMQ is empty. If I run the command `php /orders/bin/console app:collect-orders` in dev mode, the queue gets created automatically. However, if I run it in prod mode `php /orders/bin/console app:collect-orders -e prod`, the queue is never created and the command crashes with the "queue not found" error.

My temporary solution is to call the command once in the beginning of docker-compose runtime with `-e dev` parameter, which is not very nice.

Does anyone know how to create queue if it does not exist?